# which enzyme phosphorylates sodium potassium pump?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

I know that Na+/k+ pump possess atp-ase function; so the pump will hydrolyze ATP into ADP + Pi. And I see in a figure that the pump is phosphorylated but couldn't really find which protein catalyzes this.

Does the pump act as a phosphorylase??

Or is there a separate enzyme present nearby that does this?

Comment: What figure?  Go figure why a pump needs ATP, or read the associated text. Come back and post when you’ve researched your question better.

Comment: Also: Please add a link where you read this.